# There is a way to store variables from .env online so my team can use the variables but the values keep secret?

Tags: environment-variables, cloud, devops, infrastructure

I'm trying to optimize and make more safe my repository that I have my applications.

Today, I've two `.env` files:

- `.env.local` (has the values from variables to run the app on local)
- `.env.prod`(has the values from variables to run the app local but pointing to prod)

I wish to know if there something on the internet that I can store the values from the variables so my team can use but they can't see what the real value is.
Like, they can use the `.env.local` or `.env.prod` but they don't have access to it.

Answer (score 2):

There is a method to make the way you store the .env values better. Check out  [https://www.dotenv.org/](https://www.dotenv.org)

All of your environment variables can be kept in this location, and they will create a vault address for you to use in your project.
[image]

Separately managing the environments for development and production is also beneficial. By avoiding the need to visit each deployed platform and switch environment settings, it saves you time.